# Create IP.txt from Hostnames.txt

Tags: powershell

What am I doing wrong?

I want to create a new text file containing IP Addresses from a text file containing only Hostnames.

```
function Get-HostToIP($hostname) { 
    $result = [system.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($hostname) 
    $result.AddressList | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString }
}
Get-Content "hostnames.txt" | ForEach-Object {(Get-HostToIP($_)) >> ip.txt}
```

Comment: Dunno. What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You aren't checking for errors?

Comment: .\ is what tells it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Powershell is looking under C:\windows\system32 folder for the files. Replace the file names with full path of the files and it should work:

```
Get-Content "C:\path\to\hostnames.txt" | ForEach-Object {(Get-HostToIP($_)) >> c:\path\to\ip.txt}
```